# How to use StringReplace "from bottom to global"?

Tags: string-manipulation

Suppose I have an original string that looks like:

```
str1 = "erewrer<.rer>r33e<erer>re<><>rer\nrer<ew212>"
```

I want to get rid of all those discrete `<...>`s to get

```
"erewrerr33ererer\nrer"
```

I tried `StringReplace`

```
StringReplace[str1, "<" ~~ __ ~~ ">" -> ""]
```

but it produced

```
"erewrer"
```

which is the result with the outermost `<...>` removed.

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `Shortest[]` to get the shortest consistent match(es), since *Mathematica* uses `Longest[]` (i.e. a greedy match) by default:

```
StringReplace["erewrer<.rer>r33e<erer>re<><>rer\nrer<ew212>", 
              Shortest["<" ~~ __ ~~ ">"] -> ""]
   "erewrerr33ererer\nrer"
```

Comment: Regex version: `StringReplace[str1, RegularExpression["<(?s).+?>"] -> ""]`