# Shortest[] didn't work for StringReplace for shortest consistent match if whiteSpace involved

Tags: string-manipulation

This is a problem related to [How to use StringReplace "from bottom to global"?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/108094/how-to-use-stringreplace-from-bottom-to-global)

The answer of @J.M. works well for "<...>" styles :

```
StringReplace["erewrer<.rer>r33e<erer>re<><>rer\nrer<ew212>", 
          Shortest["<" ~~ __ ~~ ">"] -> ""]
"erewrerr33ererer\nrer"
```

Now suppose I have a string

```
strinput="It will only take a moment/minute/second"
```

I want to get

```
 stroutput="It will only take a second"
```

So I tried

```
StringReplace[#, {Shortest[" " ~~ ___ ~~ "/"] -> 
 " "}] &@"It will only take a moment/minute/second"

"It minute/second"
```

Strangely the whole "will only take a moment/" was eaten. Why this happen? What should I do?

Comment: Try `{" " ~~ Except[" "] .. ~~ "/" -> " "}` and take a look here: [72283](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72283/5478)

Comment: For things like this, tag the pattern and print, e.g. `StringReplace[#, {xx : Shortest[" " ~~ ___ ~~ "/"] :> (Print[xx]; 
      " ")}] &@"It will only take a moment/minute/second"` and you can see exactly what's matched (and that it's doing what you asked it to in this case).